# Puppet - silently exit if the source is not available

Tags: puppet

Is it possible to silently exit if the source file is not available.

For example:

```
file {"/tmp/skin-${version}_${theme}.zip":
        source => "${file_location}/skin-${version}_${theme}.zip",
        ensure  => file,
        mode    => '0700'
    }
->
exec {"commands":  
         Here I will be processing the above downloaded file, if the url is not valid this block should not execute.
    }
```

In the above example if the file -> source url is not available, this should silently exit without any error.

Comment: Where is this file being hosted? If it is in the module, then when would it not exist?

Comment: yes it's in module. lets say in `skin.pp` file and the code is in class `dev:skin_it`, which is being called from some other module.

Comment: Then the file would always exist in the `files` directory inside the module, so you are fine.

Comment: On running I can see the error on the console, what I want to give a proper message(notify) rather than the error.

Comment: How about just fixing the error?

Comment: Actually I have to check first whether the file is there at source, if yes proceed and do operation on the file, if source file not present just exit the code and notify a message ' source file not available'

Answer (score 0):

With an [onlyif](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/types/exec.html#exec-attribute-onlyif) on your exec it will only trigger if the test succeeds.

```
  exec { 'command':
    onlyif => "test -f /tmp/skin-${version}_${theme}.zip"
  }
```

Comment: ${file_location} is a some url, would the test command work on urls??

Comment: No sorry I overread that. You have to check on the file so you would test: `"test -f /tmp/skin-${version}_${theme}.zip"`